# Capturing all click events in user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm developing a custom list sort of idea, which consists basically of usercontrols stacked vertically in a FlowLayoutPanel.  I'm writing it this way so that I can add buttons that appear on the list item when it is selected.

The list item control has a few labels on it and some panels, so in order to determine whether the whole list item was clicked on (to select it, and make the buttons appear), I have to add click event handlers to all the labels and panels etc.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, by capturing all the click events for the control, kinda like KeyPreview, but for click events.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add a Rectangle over the top of the user controls and paint with a transparent brush then add the click handler to this.

Andrew

Comment: A Rectangle?  As in a System.Drawing.Rectangle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347439/custom-controls-in-c-winforms-mouse-event-question

Answer (score 0):

I solved it eventually by overriding WndProc like so:

```
public partial class ListItem: UserControl
{
    private const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
        {
            Debug.Print("Activated!");
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I reckon this is probably the easiest solution.  Still, thanks for the suggestions Andrew!