# mouse event fires when I mouse over child control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, winapp

Ok, so I have this control that has some other controls on it.

[image: control with controls on it]

I have set the controls mouse enter and mouse leave events.  My problem is that the mouse leave event fires if I mouse over any of the child controls (like the name box for example).

What I need is for the mouse leave event to fire when my mouse leaves the entire control, rather than firing when I mouse over any of the child controls.  Any suggestions?

Here are the events as I have them so far:

```
Private Sub DeliveryControl_MouseEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseEnter
    Me.removeImage.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub DeliveryControl_MouseLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseLeave
    Me.removeImage.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the event code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347439/custom-controls-in-c-windows-forms-mouse-event-question) question may address your problem. Basically you work out whether your mouse is over a child control or not using GetChildAtPoint.