# MouseHover not firing when mouse is down

Tags: c#, winforms, mousehover

I'm working on a WordSearch puzzle program (also called WordFind) where you have to find certain words in a mass of letters. I'm using C# WinForms.

My problem is when I want to click and hold 1 letter(`Label`), then drag over to other letters to change their `ForeColor`.  I've tried googling but to no avail.

Here is what I have:

```
foreach (Letter a in game.GetLetters())
{
     this.Controls.Add(a);
     a.MouseDown += (s, e2) =>
     {
         isDown = true;
         a.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
     };
     a.MouseUp += (s, e2) =>
     {
         isDown = false;
     };
     a.MouseHover += (s, e2) =>
     {
         if (isDown)
             a.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
     };
}
```

However, the MouseHover event never fires unless the mouse is not being held down. Also no luck swapping `MouseHover` with `MouseEnter`. So, I kept the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events and tried using MouseHover within the form itself:

```
private void frmMain_MouseHover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDown)
    {
        foreach (Letter l in game.GetLetters())
           if (l.ClientRectangle.Contains(l.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
               l.ForeColor = Color.Purple;
    }
}
```

This event does not fire either and I'm at a loss as to why it's not firing and what some alternative solutions are.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You could use a timer and check if the mouse button is down then the code from `frmMain_MouseHover` should be executed. You could check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159534/net-how-to-check-if-the-mouse-is-in-a-control)

Comment: Awesome solution! Thinkin outside the box! Tysm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Drag and Drop events.

1. Set [`AllowDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.allowdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) property for each control that is target of drop.
2. Handle `MouseDown` event for each control that drag starts with it and in the handler call [`DoDragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) event of that control and set the data that you want to drag.
3. Handle [`DragEnetr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter(v=vs.110).aspx) event of each target of drag and set [`e.Effect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.effect(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if drop is allowed or not. Here is the place that you can check if drop is allowed,  change the back color to your desired color.
4. Handle [`DragLeave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave(v=vs.110).aspx) to reset the back color.
5. Hanlde [`DragDrop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) and use `GetData` method if [`e.Data`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.data(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the data and perform the actions when drop.

**walking through**

- [Walkthrough: Performing a Drag-and-Drop Operation in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0.aspx)

**Example**

I have 3 buttons, button1 and button2 and button3 and button2 is target of drop. In the below code, I'll check if the text that will drop on button 2, is the text of button1, I'll change the back color of button 2 to green, else to red. also if you take dragging mouse out of button2, I'll set the back color to default. If you drop, I'll change the text of button2 and will set the text of button1:

```
//Start drag for button 2
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.DoDragDrop(this.button1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

//Start drag for button 3
private void button3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.button3.DoDragDrop(this.button3.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

//Check if drop is allowed and change back color
private void button2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString()== button1.Text)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        this.button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        this.button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}

//Perform drop actions
private void button2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    this.button2.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
}

//Reset back color here
private void button2_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button2.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
}
```

Comment: Tysm for the suggestion, going to play around with these events and see if this would work better. Always thought these events were only for dragging files onto the form.

Comment: You are welcome  :) let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you could solve the problem :)

Comment: By the way, when a post answers your question, you can kindly accept it by click on check mark and vote for it using up arrow :) [Accepting answers, How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) You can only accept one answer, but you can vote up as many answers you find helpful, including the accepted one.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the various drag events:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragover(v=vs.110).aspx

etc...

The problem that you are running into is that you are using the wrong events for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: How exactly is this not an answer? He's using the wrong events. Don't go downvoting people just because you don't know how to fix his problem. Using a timer is a stupid and needless way of solving this solution when he can get the exact results he is looking for by using the drag events instead of click. . . .

Comment: @AnthonyHart Your answer is technically correct +1 to your answer. But it's better to add more details to answer, like I did :) Hope you find the answer helpful :)

Comment: You cannot post a bunch of links without any explanation. At least, you should write that the events he used doesn't fit in this situation and he needs to use something else (specify the events and how to use them). It's important to have links in the answer but they can change so it makes sence to cite them in your answer. My comment may be wrong that's why it's a comment but not an answer. I totally agree that using of a timer is not the best approach. Please improve your answer and people will upvote it.